# Centos 7 i686 Log entries

Tags: centos

It appears that my system has a built in bootable recovery image that appears when it doesn't boot to windows and it presents it self as a SMI USB drive. Linux is picking this up as SDE which doesn't seem to be much as problem as it boots to Linux. But I do see these entries in the log file and I don't know what to do as I can't disable the drive in the BIOS.

```
[393557.698903]  sde: sde1
[393867.959949]  sde: sde1
[394178.251816]  sde: sde1
[394489.042878]  sde: sde1
[394789.177137]  sde: sde1
[395099.173050]  sde: sde1
[395409.474945]  sde: sde1
[395709.727596]  sde: sde1
[396020.067186]  sde: sde1
[396330.303474]  sde: sde1
[396630.603381]  sde: sde1
[396940.895266]  sde: sde1
[397251.674885]  sde: sde1
[397561.602063]  sde: sde1
[397861.872556]  sde: sde1
[398172.162149]  sde: sde1
[398482.432055]  sde: sde1
[398782.742333]  sde: sde1
[399092.973831]  sde: sde1
[399403.899133]  sde: sde1
[399704.122881]  sde: sde1
[400013.936796]  sde: sde1
[400324.220148]  sde: sde1
[400634.596273]  sde: sde1
[400934.794514]  sde: sde1
[401245.089120]  sde: sde1
[401548.017357]  sde: sde1
[401858.391986]  sde: sde1
[402158.672756]  sde: sde1
[402469.841677]  sde: sde1
[402779.379326]  sde: sde1
[403079.691135]  sde: sde1
[403389.964803]  sde: sde1
[403700.259804]  sde: sde1
[404010.583317]  sde: sde1
```

Comment: And what's the actual problem here?

Comment: I would like to know what is causing these entries to appear in the log, fix the issue if there is one and prevent the messages.